# VariableSizedWrapGrid like uniformgrid

Tags: uwp, uniformgrid, variablesizedwrapgrid

I am trying to build a colour picker. Currently I am using a  ‘ItemsControl‘ with a ‚VariableSizedWrapGrid‘ as ‚ItemsPanel‘. The ‚ItemTemplate‘ consists of a Button. Currently the ‘button’ uses a fixed size, but it would be nicer when the buttons size automatically like in the ‘uniformgrid’ from ‘wpf’. Is it possible to for the ‚VariableSizedWrapGrid‘ to act like a ‘uniformgrid’?

Comment: Check https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control

Comment: Maybe the ffuidwrappanel can help https://github.com/ratishphilip/CompositionProToolkit